# Method Info is returning null, uncertain to why

Tags: c#, reflection, methodinfo

```
sealed public class HMethod
{
    public int Calc(string Method, int X1, int X2, int Y1, int Y2)
    {
        MethodInfo HMethodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod(Method);
        return (int)HMethodInfo.Invoke(
            this, 
            new object[4] { X1, X2, Y1, Y2 }
            );
    }
    int ManhattanH(int X1, int X2, int Y1, int Y2)
    {
        //Blah
    }
    int LineH(int X1, int X2, int Y1, int Y2)
    {
        //Blah
    }
    //Other Heuristics
}
```

When calling `new HMethod().Calc("ManhattanH". X1, X2, Y1, Y2)` HMethodInfo is null. Creates a null reference Exception. It should call the Method passed in via text (Which is grabbed from a text file)

Resolved: Methods are private.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ManhattanH is private method. Make this method is public or use BindingFlags.NonPublic.

Comment: Don't forget, if you manually give `GetMethod` binding flags, you need to include `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic`, not just `BindingFlags.NonPublic`.

Answer (score 1):

`GetMethod` automatically searches only for public members of that type. You can get around this (and have the search include private members) by substituting in this line:

```
MethodInfo HMethodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod(Method, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Type.GetMethod Method (String, Type[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zz808e6.aspx)

> The search for name is case-sensitive. The search includes public static and public instance methods.
>
> You cannot omit parameters when looking up constructors and methods.
> You can only omit parameters when invoking.

Change your method to public and try this:

```
MethodInfo HMethodInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod(Method,
    new Type[]{typeof(int), typeof(int), typeof(int), typeof(int)});
```

Comment: The type argument isn't necessary in this case. The real problem is that the requested method is private

Comment: @AlexBrault are you suggesting that the documentation is wrong?

Comment: I'm saying I just tried omitting the types and it works perfectly. I'm a bit confused as to why, because I agree that the documentation seems to indicate we'd need to pass them

Comment: Ah ha! We're fine because there's only one method with the requested name. If I add an overload, I get an AmbiguousMatchException

Comment: I see. Looks like the documentation is ambiguous and I'm a bit too lazy to have checked it

Comment: @surfen that documentation is actually backwards.  If you omit parameters when you invoke you get a TargetParameterCountException.  It may be possible if the method has default parameters, but that note you quoted from the docs is also there for .net 2.0.

Comment: It's funny how they "fixed" the example from .net 2.0 to 4.0 to be compatible with this note, by removing parameters from the method